# get field name from one app to another app in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

We have defined two apps: `Manin_matrix` and `SW_matrix`.

We want the field name (`project_name`) present in class `GENERAL_t` of `models.py` file inside `Main_matrix` app to be inside the `models.py` file of `SW_matrix app`.

Basically, `project_name_work` field in class `EDVT` of `SW_matrix` `models.py` should be the same as `project_name` of `Main_matrix` app.
We want this so that in a database for `EDVT` table we will get the same project id along with the project name.

Main_matrix/models.py

```py
    class GENERAL_t(models.Model):
        project_name = models.CharField(
            blank=True,
            null=True,
            max_length=40,
            verbose_name='Project_Name'
        )
        platform = models.CharField(
            blank=True,
            null=True,
            max_length=40,
            verbose_name='Platform SW'
        )
```

SW_matrix/models.py

```py
    class EDVT(models.Model):
        project_rel=models.ForeignKey(
            GENERAL_t,
            null=True,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
            verbose_name="Choose Project"
        )
        project_name_work = models.ForeignKey(
            GENERAL_t.project_name,
            null=True,
            verbose_name='Project_Name'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that, and a FK won't allow that. The FK field is just the ID of a row in another table, nothing more complex than that really.

When working with `ForeignKey` links like this it's a good idea to use strings so that you don't have to import the related model. The format of the string is `'<appname.ModelName>`

For example, I link an object to a (django) content type like this;

```
source_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
    verbose_name=_('source content type'),
    to='contenttypes.ContentType',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

So to link your `EDVT` model to a `GENERAL_t` you'd do;

```py
    class EDVT(models.Model):
        general_t = models.ForeignKey(
            to='Manin_matrix.GENERAL_t',
            null=True,
            verbose_name='general t'
        )
```

Then if `EDVT` needs to be able to return a `project_name` you could do it as a property.

```py
    class EDVT(models.Model):
        project_rel = models.ForeignKey(
            to='Manin_matrix.GENERAL_t',
            null=True,
            verbose_name='Project_Name'
        )

        @property
        def project_name(self):
            return self.project_rel.project_name
```

Then you can access it either by `EDVT.objects.first().project_name` or if you didn't implement the `property` you can do `EDVT.objects.first().general_t.project_name` (or any other field on that model)

Comment: so here project_rel is general_t in our case and we tried with @property. But it showed error in self. And it did not worked also at database. Not able to save the string. Just showed id

Comment: @DivyankGarg What's the error? And the ID is all you'll get for a ForeignKey field.